# Filtering json using jq

Tags: json, linux, jq

Within an Azure DevOps pipeline, running via a linux build agent, I'm looking to use jq to take specific keys/values from a json file containing an array of data, sort the array by date and filter out unnecessary results based on one of the values.

So far I have the below which does a lot of this for me. test2.json is just a test example for now while I do a proof of concept. This will change to an API call.

```
jq '[.value[] | {id: .id, date: .finishedDate, state: .state, result: .result}] | sort_by(.finishedDate)' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/test2.json
```

The above code works. It reduces the larger array in test2.json to just the fields for id, finishedDate, state and result. It also sorted the result by finishedDate which is what I need it to do. Below is an example of the json off the back of the above code.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1902,
        "date": "2023-06-19T13:08:17.6903656Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded"
    },
    {
        "id": 1668,
        "date": "2023-06-19T13:00:18.9255899Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "failed"
    },
    {
        "id": 1621,
        "date": "2023-06-14T12:11:10.2714172Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "failed"
    },
    {
        "id": 1569,
        "date": "2023-06-14T08:20:34.0988263Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded"
    },
    {
        "id": 1566,
        "date": "2023-06-14T08:29:32.1229317Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded"
    },
    {
        "id": 1564,
        "date": "2023-06-14T07:48:54.1384016Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "failed"
    },
    {
        "id": 1557,
        "date": "2023-06-14T07:36:16.8346765Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "succeeded"
    },
    {
        "id": 1555,
        "date": "2023-06-14T07:24:19.5030833Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "failed"
    },
    {
        "id": 1553,
        "date": "2023-06-14T07:11:50.4071939Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "failed"
    },
    {
        "id": 1551,
        "date": "2023-06-14T06:58:34.3160857Z",
        "state": "completed",
        "result": "failed"
    }
]
```

The final part I need to do is select only entries where result = "succeeded". I believe I need to add something like `select(.result="succeeded")` based on the documentation I read online however depending on where I add this into my jq query I either get an error e.g. no such file found or I get the same results as above with the select(.result="succeeded") having no impact (see below jq query).

```
jq '[.value[] | select(.result="succeeded") | {id: .id, date: .finishedDate, state: .state, result: .result}] | sort_by(.finishedDate)' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/test2.json
```

I'm fairly new to using jq so I imagine I'm missing something small to get this working and I'm hoping someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(select(.result=="succeeded") | { id, date: .finishedDate, state, result }) | sort_by(.date)
```

Gives the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1557,
    "date": "2023-06-14T07:36:16.8346765Z",
    "state": "completed",
    "result": "succeeded"
  },
  {
    "id": 1569,
    "date": "2023-06-14T08:20:34.0988263Z",
    "state": "completed",
    "result": "succeeded"
  },
  {
    "id": 1566,
    "date": "2023-06-14T08:29:32.1229317Z",
    "state": "completed",
    "result": "succeeded"
  },
  {
    "id": 1902,
    "date": "2023-06-19T13:08:17.6903656Z",
    "state": "completed",
    "result": "succeeded"
  }
]
```

---

- `id: .id` can be shorten to just `id`
- The `select()` needs to be inside the `map()`
- `sort_by()` after the `select()` so we don't need to sort those we're removing

---

##### [Online Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5j3DnnGXe1i)

Comment: Thanks this works. Comparing your code to what I attempted e.g. `jq '[.value[] | select(.result="succeeded") | {id: .id, date: .finishedDate, state: .state, result: .result}] | sort_by(.finishedDate)' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/test2.json` the key part that I was missing was the double == which I should have spotted e.g. this works `jq '[.value[] | select(.result=="succeeded") | {id: .id, date: .finishedDate, state: .state, result: .result}] | sort_by(.finishedDate)' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/test2.json
`. Thanks again.